# Wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: libraries, arm, x86, cpu-architecture

I'm in an ARM machine and I wanted to use an x86 program.
Installed Box86 and the program and it's libraries.

The program crashes because of this error: `Error initializing native *libname* (last dlerror is *libname*: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64)`. This error is repeated several times for each of the libraries I installed.

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/436815), it's beacause they are 64 bit libraries, but I made sure to install the i386 version of the packages.
Also, their workaround doesen't solve the problem for me, causing the same output.

Any clue of what's happening here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Box86's Github page](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86), it uses the native (i.e. ARM) versions of some system libraries instead of the x86 ones. And since Box86 seems to need a 32-bit ARM subsystem to run, I think it's trying to say it needs a **32-bit ARM version** of `*libname*`.

Comment: You're right! In fact, in Box86's repo there is a [Steam installer script](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86/blob/master/install_steam.sh), that installs libraries for armhf.